# Метод Random.setSeed()

Tags: java

Здраствуйте скажите прошу детально что делает метод setSeed() с класса Random в java,  какое отношение он имеет к атомарности и почему он synchronized. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Генератор псевдослучайных чисел (ГПСЧ) начинает свою работу с определенной точки в пространстве возможных чисел. Эта точка называется начальным числом (англ. seed).
Если вы установите seed = 2 то у вас ваш ГПСЧ всегда будет выдавать одну и ту же последовательность чисел.

Answer (score 1):

В документации вполне четко написано.
Метод `setSeed()` устанавливает начальное число этого ГПСЧ.
`setSeed()` изменяет состояние экземпляра ГПСЧ так, чтобы он находился в том же состоянии, как если бы он был только что создан с аргументом `seed` в качестве начального числа.
Метод `setSeed()` реализуется классом Random путем атомарного (то есть неделимого, полностью выполняемого одним потоком (поэтому `synchronized`)) обновления начального числа до `(seed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)` и очистки флага `haveNextNextGaussian`, используемого методом `nextGaussian()`.